# Giving pause of second in Google text to speech using python

Tags: python-3.x, gtts

```
from gtts import gTTS 
import os
import random

with open('symbols.txt', 'r') as file:
    symbols = file.read().replace('\n', '')

def getunique():
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                unique.add(file.split('.')[0])
            
            
def generate(unique):
    chars = symbols
    while True:
        value = "".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(8))
        if value not in unique:
            language = 'en'
            myobj = gTTS(text=value, lang=language, slow=True) 
            myobj.save("audio_captcha_training_set2/"+value+".mp3")
            unique.add(value)
            break

path = "C:\\Users\\DNS\\Desktop\\Audio Captcha\\Test Python code\\audio_captcha_training_set\\"
unique = set()
getunique()

for _ in range(20):
    generate(unique)
```

Here is a code which reads a file in which there is characters from 0-9 and A-Z. This is generating audio for random 8 characters reading from file but it does not give any pause or delay while generating audio of characters. I want to add a pause of a second between each characters. Any help?

Comment: `import time; time.sleep(1)`

Comment: Can you pin point where should I add time.sleep(1) in the actual code? and can I add half a second sleep time?

Comment: Just after the point where you sent in a character, which i guess is after `generate(unique)`. The value `1` is a second, for half a second use `0.5`.

Comment: The sleep command adds sleep mode for the code and it does not produce any effect to the audio.

Comment: If you want breaks between the audio, you have to add a ` ` (space). In any case use: `value = " ".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(8))` (note the space in `" ".join`. Besides that there is no support for it than you already found using `slow=True`, as indicate in the issues [here](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/40) and [here](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/41). Best solution is to increase more spaces or adjust the `.mp3` file, either manually or while reading it with python change the speed (which depends on the module of how to do it.)